# How to display image from MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I am trying to display avatar which is fetched from server which takes avatar from MySql db. I am receiving image from server as arrayBuffer which is saved in state.

[image: React code]

[image: States]

And server side:

[image: Server]

Answer (score 0):

You can view with base64 encode;

```
function toBase64(arr) {
   return btoa(arr.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''));
}
```

How to use?

```
<img src={`data:image/png;base64,${toBase64(response.data.avatar)}`} />
```